# Angularjs form vaidation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation, angularjs-ng-form

I have a list of contacts on my page, each is displayed inside an `<input>` field (they're all inside a `<form>` element. When I click on a field and edit it, I want to have some validation - for example, if the field is not empty, I want to give this field a red BG and/or display a message below this exact field. So I tried this:

```
<form name="contactsForm" ng-submit="update()" novalidate>
    <tr class="row">
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for contact" ng-model="filter.userSearch"/>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-delete" ng-click="clearSearchField()"></button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="toggleNewContact()">Add User</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Update</button>
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="row" ng-if="addNewContact" ng-repeat="new in newContacts">

        <td><input type="text" class="col-md-12 form-control" ng-model="new.en_name"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="col-md-12 form-control" ng-model="new.email"></td>
        <td>
            <button ng-click="addMore()" class="btn btn-sm btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></button>
            <button ng-click="addLess(new)" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row" ng-repeat="contact in contactList | filter:filter.userSearch track by $index">
        <td class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : contactsForm.en_name.$invalid && !contactsForm.en_name.$pristine }">
            <input type="text" class="col-md-12 form-control" ng-model="contact.en_name" name="en_name" required>
            <p ng-show="contactsForm.en_name.$invalid && !contactsForm.en_name.$pristine" class="help-block">Name in English is required.</p>
        </td>
        <td>
             <input type="text" class="col-md-12 form-control" ng-model="contact.email" name="{{contact.email}}" required>
        </td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

That didn't work, I didn't see any message. I also tried this:

```
<input type="text" class="col-md-12 form-control" ng-model="contact.en_name" name="{{contact.en_name}}" required>
```

But I didn't know how to connect this part `name="{{contact.en_name}}"` to this `<p ng-show="contactsForm.en_name.$invalid && !contactsForm.en_name.$pristine"`.

I also tried using `$index` as name:

```
<td class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : contactsForm.$index.$invalid && !contactsForm.$index.$pristine }">
    <input type="text" class="col-md-12 form-control" ng-model="contact.en_name" name="{{$index}}" required>
    <p ng-show="contactsForm.$index.$invalid && !contactsForm.$index.$pristine" class="help-block">Name in English is required.</p>
</td>
```

But that also didn't work - I didn't see any error message.

What am I doing wrong and how can I make it work?

Comment: In your first snippet just add `required` attribute to the input.

Comment: may I know why you want `name` attribute of input field based on `ng-model` value `contact.en_name`?

Comment: @dfsq But it has it... `<input type="text" class="col-md-12 form-control" ng-model="contact.en_name" name="en_name" **required**>`

Comment: @PankajParkar From what I read, I must have `name` attribute to make form validation, am I not? Any suggestions how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your all the input fields inside `ng-repeat` having same name attribute(so all were pointing to same `name` in form object), so somehow you need to make each name attribute to be unique. You could use `$index` to make it unique.

**Markup**

```
<td class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : contactsForm['en_name'+$index].$invalid && !contactsForm['en_name'+$index].$pristine }">
   <input type="text" class="col-md-12 form-control" 
     ng-model="contact.en_name" ng-attr-name="{{'en_name'+$index}}" required>
   <p ng-show="contactsForm['en_name'+$index].$invalid && !contactsForm['en_name'+$index].$pristine" 
    class="help-block">
      Name in English is required.
    </p>
</td>
```

Comment: Tried it, but unfortunately it still didn't work. I tried to change the name to `name="en_name_{{$index}}"` and then validation to `<p ng-show="contactsForm['en_name_'+$index].$invalid && !contactsForm['en_name_'+$index].$pristine"
                               class="help-block">`, but still no error message.

Comment: Tried it, still nothing. BTW, when I look at code inspector, that's what I see: `ng-attr-name="{{'en_name'+$index}}"`, without the actual index number.

Comment: @Igal could you give me plunkr so that I can dig into it..though I'm sure above should work..

Comment: OK, I was working on the plunkr, and then I noticed a mistake that I had - my `<form>` element was defined in incorrect place, should've been before the `<table>` element. So I changed that, tried it with the name I mentioned previously `name="en_name_{{$index}}"` and validation I mentioned on the same reply `<p ng-show="contactsForm['en_name_'+$index].$invalid && !contactsForm['en_name_'+$index].$pristine" class="help-block">` and... it finally worked!!! Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @Igal glad to know that.. Thanks :-)